# How to comment with the mobile Stack Exchange App?

Tags: support, comments, mobile-app

I only figured out how to comment on another comment, but I want to comment on an answer.

Comment: By "comment on another comment", do you mean "respond to a comment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ... can't comment on another comment. When you comment on another post (question or answer), your comment will appear under the previous comment; they are always shown in chronological order. It might *seem* like you're commenting on another comment, but you're actually commenting on the post itself.

As @rene notes, you need a certain amount of reputation to comment on all posts. On Meta Stack Exchange, it's 5 reputation; on your other site, Ask Ubuntu, it's [50](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). Before you reach that level, you can only comment on your own posts, or on answers to your own question.

Comment: Yes but can't you @name to reply to that comment under them?

Comment: That's possible, yes, but that was not what the OP seems to have problems with.

Comment: Do note that the OP doesn't seem to have the [comment everywhere privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) ([50 rep needed on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment)) on any of the sites they have an account on. Although  it might be awesome for the use of the app if it lift all limits found on the full website but that is not reality yet ...